# struct.error: argument out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, binary

Создал набор данных в формате `0х********` и пытаюсь их записать в bin файл. При записи возникает такая проблема:

```
data = pack(format_1, int(word, 16)) 
struct.error: argument out of range
```

Кусок кода, где начинается ошибка:

```
a = open('1part_particion.txt', 'r')
# Запись 4-ого bin  файла
f_bin_4 = open('4test.bin', 'wb')
for line in a:
    word = line[0:10]
    format_1 = "1i"
    data = pack(format_1, int(word, 16))
    f_bin_4.write(data)
f_bin_4.close()
```

Набор данных из файла, ошибка с 0 итерации:

```
0x20101010
0x10101000
0x00000010
0x10001010
0x10101000
0x00101010
0x10001010
0x10001010
0x10100010
0x10000000
0x00000010
0x10101010
0x0049E01C
0x5B5BD1D1
0x4924C8F8
0x42424C1C
0xE047D1F8
```

А вот для данного набора ошибка идет только с 8 итерации:

```
0x08395557
0x595B5D00
0x0000005F
0x61006365
0x67696B00
0x006D6F71
0x73007577
0x79007B7D
0x817F0081
0x83000000
0x00000085
0x87898B8D
0x7013491C
```

Если я сделаю `line[0:9]`, то все файлы спокойно создаются, но с 1 условием: некоторые из строк данных в них обрезаются с конца (на 1 символ)

В чем моя ошибка?

Весь код программы ниже:

```
# Запись информации в ПЗУ
from struct import *

# ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ

global flag_start
global end
global flag_end1
flag_start = 0
flag_end1 = 2
end = 0
str = '!'
string = '\n'

'''Открываем файл с данными'''
f_txt = open('2.txt', 'r')
'''Создаем файлы для записи данных для каждой микросхемы'''
f1_txt = open('1part.txt', 'w')
f2_txt = open('2part.txt', 'w')
f3_txt = open('3part.txt', 'w')
f4_txt = open('4part.txt', 'w')
f1_txt_result = open('1part_particion.txt', 'w')
f2_txt_result = open('2part_particion.txt', 'w')
f3_txt_result = open('3part_particion.txt', 'w')
f4_txt_result = open('4part_particion.txt', 'w')
'''Читаем построчно'''
# for line in f_txt:
# #  line - строка с данными
# #  записали биты в файл ( 32 бита данных)
#     f1_txt.write(line[0:1] + line[2:3] + '\n')
#     f2_txt.write(line[0:1] + line[4:5] + '\n')
#     f3_txt.write(line[0:1] + line[6:7] + '\n')
#     f4_txt.write(line[0:1] + line[8:9] + '\n')
f_txt.close()
f1_txt.close()
f2_txt.close()
f3_txt.close()
f4_txt.close()

# # Подсче количество строк в каждом файле
# num_lines_1 = sum(1 for line in open('1part.txt'))
# num_lines_2 = sum(1 for line in open('2part.txt'))
# num_lines_3 = sum(1 for line in open('3part.txt'))
# num_lines_4 = sum(1 for line in open('4part.txt'))

# Нарезка №1 готовых к переводу в bin файлов
f_txt = open('2.txt', 'r')
f1_txt = open('1part.txt', 'w')
for line in f_txt:
    f1_txt.write(line[2] + line[3] + '!')
f1_txt.close()
f1_txt = open('1part.txt', 'r')
for line in f1_txt:
    num_lines_1 = len(line)
    end = num_lines_1 - 1
    while flag_end1 < end:
        flag_start = line.find(str, flag_start, num_lines_1)
        flag_end = line.find(str, flag_start + 1, num_lines_1)
        flag_start1 = line.find(str, flag_end + 1, num_lines_1)
        flag_end1 = line.find(str, flag_start1 + 1, num_lines_1)
        result_split = '0x' + line[flag_start - 2:flag_end - 3] + line[flag_start + 1:flag_end] + line[flag_end + 1:flag_start1] + line[flag_start1 + 1:flag_end1] + '\n'
        f1_txt_result.write(result_split)
        if flag_end1 == num_lines_1:
            break
        flag_start = flag_end1 + 1
f1_txt.close()
f1_txt_result.close()
flag_start = 0
flag_end1 = 2
end = 0

# Нарезка №2 готовых к переводу в bin файлов
f_txt = open('2.txt', 'r')
f2_txt = open('2part.txt', 'w')
for line in f_txt:
    f2_txt.write(line[4] + line[5] + '!')
f2_txt.close()
f2_txt = open('2part.txt', 'r')
for line in f2_txt:
    num_lines_2 = len(line)
    end = num_lines_2 - 1
    while flag_end1 < end:
        flag_start = line.find(str, flag_start, num_lines_2)
        flag_end = line.find(str, flag_start + 1, num_lines_2)
        flag_start1 = line.find(str, flag_end + 1, num_lines_2)
        flag_end1 = line.find(str, flag_start1 + 1, num_lines_2)
        result_split = '0x' + line[flag_start - 2:flag_end - 3] + line[flag_start + 1:flag_end] + line[flag_end + 1:flag_start1] + line[flag_start1 + 1:flag_end1] + '\n'
        f2_txt_result.write(result_split)
        if flag_end1 == num_lines_2:
            break
        flag_start = flag_end1 + 1
f2_txt.close()
f2_txt_result.close()
flag_start = 0
flag_end1 = 2
end = 0

# Нарезка №3 готовых к переводу в bin файлов
f_txt = open('2.txt', 'r')
f3_txt = open('3part.txt', 'w')
for line in f_txt:
    f3_txt.write(line[6] + line[7] + '!')
f3_txt.close()
f3_txt = open('3part.txt', 'r')
for line in f3_txt:
    num_lines_3 = len(line)
    end = num_lines_3 - 1
    while flag_end1 < end:
        flag_start = line.find(str, flag_start, num_lines_3)
        flag_end = line.find(str, flag_start + 1, num_lines_3)
        flag_start1 = line.find(str, flag_end + 1, num_lines_3)
        flag_end1 = line.find(str, flag_start1 + 1, num_lines_3)
        result_split = '0x' + line[flag_start - 2:flag_end - 3] + line[flag_start + 1:flag_end] + line[flag_end + 1:flag_start1] + line[flag_start1 + 1:flag_end1] + '\n'
        f3_txt_result.write(result_split)
        if flag_end1 == num_lines_3:
            break
        flag_start = flag_end1 + 1
f3_txt.close()
f3_txt_result.close()
flag_start = 0
flag_end1 = 2
end = 0
# Нарезка №4 готовых к переводу в bin файлов
f_txt = open('2.txt', 'r')
f4_txt = open('4part.txt', 'w')
for line in f_txt:
    f4_txt.write(line[8] + line[9] + '!')
f4_txt.close()
f4_txt = open('4part.txt', 'r')
for line in f4_txt:
    num_lines_4 = len(line)
    end = num_lines_4 - 1
    while flag_end1 < end:
        flag_start = line.find(str, flag_start, num_lines_4)
        flag_end = line.find(str, flag_start + 1, num_lines_4)
        flag_start1 = line.find(str, flag_end + 1, num_lines_4)
        flag_end1 = line.find(str, flag_start1 + 1, num_lines_4)
        result_split = '0x' + line[flag_start - 2:flag_end - 3] + line[flag_start + 1:flag_end] + line[flag_end + 1:flag_start1] + line[flag_start1 + 1:flag_end1] + '\n'
        f4_txt_result.write(result_split)
        if flag_end1 == num_lines_4:
            break
        flag_start = flag_end1 + 1
f4_txt.close()
f4_txt_result.close()

'''Открываем файл с данными'''
clear_bin_1 = open('1test.bin', 'wb')
clear_bin_1.close()
a = open('1part_particion.txt', 'r')
b = open('2part_particion.txt', 'r')
c = open('3part_particion.txt', 'r')
d = open('4part_particion.txt', 'r')

# Запись 4-ого bin  файла
f_bin_4 = open('4test.bin', 'wb')
for line in a:
    word = line[0:10]
    format_1 = "1i"
    data = pack(format_1, int(word, 16))
    f_bin_4.write(data)
f_bin_4.close()

# Запись 3-ого bin  файла
f_bin_3 = open('3test.bin', 'wb')
for line in b:
    word = line[0:10]
    format_1 = "1i"
    data = pack(format_1, int(word, 16))
    f_bin_3.write(data)
f_bin_3.close()

# Запись 2-ого bin  файла
f_bin_2 = open('2test.bin', 'wb')
for line in c:
    word = line[0:10]
    format_1 = "1i"
    data = pack(format_1, int(word, 16))
    f_bin_2.write(data)

f_bin_2.close()

# Запись 1-ого bin  файла
f_bin_1 = open('1test.bin', 'wb')
for line in d:
    word = line[0:10]
    format_1 = "1i"
    data = pack(format_1, int(word, 16))
    print(data)
    f_bin_1.write(data)

f_bin_1.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка связана с тем, что формат `'i'` предназначен для упаковки в виде **знакового** 32-битного целого, допустимые значения от `-0x80000000` (-2<sup>31</sup>) до `0x7FFFFFFF` (2<sup>31</sup>-1). Если попробовать в таком формате упаковать число больше `0x7FFFFFFF`, то получим соответствующую ошибку:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('i', 0x817F0081)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: argument out of range
argument out of range
```

На первом наборе данных на нулевой итерации такой ошибки не должно быть, т.к. там первое число явно меньше `0x7FFFFFFF`. Скорее там была бы ошибка на `0xE047D1F8`.

Чтобы избежать этой ошибки, нужно использовать беззнаковый формат `'I'` (см. [описание форматов упаковки/распаковки из модуля `struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#format-characters)):

```
>>> struct.pack('I', 0x817F0081)
b'\x81\x00\x7f\x81'
```

Также, для преобразования целых чисел в байты можно использовать встроенный метод [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes), по-умолчанию используется преобразование как беззнакового числа:

```
>>> 0x817F0081.to_bytes(4, 'little')
b'\x81\x00\x7f\x81'
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все заработало.